# Bash - wildcard to select everything but symlinks?

Tags: bash, svg, symlink

I just started an [icon project](https://github.com/sljunkie/Faenza-Reborn) at github. I don't know exactly how to handle with a massive amount of symlinks. I need to use inkscape to convert svg to png and I do it with ease with a double for loop:

```
for size in 16 22 24 32 48 64 96
do
    for i in *.svg
    do
        inkscape -f $i -w $size -h $size -e ../$size/${i%.svg}.png
    done
done
```

It's OK when there's only .svg files in the folder, but if there are symlinks this will output png's with the symlinks names, and I usually do another simple for loop to make multiple symlinks with the same name under each folder...

Answer (score 0):

[[ -L fileName ]] will return true if it's a symlink; a preceding exclamation point will mean "not". So this should work:

```
for size in 16 22 24 32 48 64 96
do
    for i in *.svg
    do
        filename=../$size/${i%.svg}.png
        if [[ ! -L $filename ]]; then
            inkscape -f $i -w $size -h $size -e $filename
        fi
    done
done
```